# Which style of weeding tool for small, densely planted flower beds and raised gardens?

Tags: tools

I bought a house with beautiful landscaping: small flowerbeds and decorative shrubs and trees, tucked away in various corners of a hilly, rocky lot. The flower beds are very densely planted.

There are a lot of hand-hoes, cultivators and weeders out there - japanese nejiri gama, dutch hoe, korean ho-mi, Cape Cod weeders, three-prong claws of numerous styles, aluminum traditional hand-hoes/cultivator, asparagus knife -  does anyone have any experience with the different types, and can offer a comparison?

Comment: depends on what your soil is like and what kind of weeds you are battling... for instance the 3-prong claw is worthless against hard dry clay soil... but it makes an appearance as a weapon in "Enter the Dragon" covered in fur, as a "Bear Claw" style prosthesis.

Comment: @Grady Player: New England top-soil. It's been well sifted and covered with mulch, tho the mulch is pretty threadbare (hence the weeder - gonna attack the weeds and re-mulch.) Weeds are mostly small leafy green things, with the occasional thistle and dandelion (which I've got a Hori-Hori for.)

Comment: maybe one of those things that looks like a sharp chipping wedge, so you can undercut them while standing up... undercutting usually good enough for small weeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have something  similar to this:

[http://www.amazon.com/DeWit-Dutch-Cape-Cod-Weeder/dp/B001P55DG0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001P55DG0)

These things are great for annual weeds, especially the Japanese Stilt Grass that is afflicting this part of North Carolina.

Comment: I wound up with the Red Pig Tools Cape Cod weeder. ( http://www.redpigtools.com/servlet/the-32/Cape-Cod-Weeder-Rt/Detail ) It is insanely useful, a true "multi-tasker" that sees more use as a cultivator, hoe and digging tool than it does as a weeder. Especially for pebbly, tough New England soil, it beats the heck out of claw-style cultivators and trowels for breaking up and moving around dirt.